# Tableau Weekly Line Graph - Need Most Recent "Null activity" to show as 0's

Tags: graph, line, tableau-api

I attached a screenshot with captions of what I need. Using tableau here which makes it a little more complicated.

My current [Line Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8y8v.jpg) just stop when activity does. I need it to continue to present day(as 0's).

I went through and used the ZN(Count[XX}) formula - Changed axis to discreet and clicked "Show Missing values" as Zero.

Need all the graphs final week to be April 16 and some to be Zero where there is no activity.

Thank you,
Charles

Comment: I think the simplest solution here would be at the data side, adding zeros  and then add a date filter in Tableau using TODAY()

Comment: So the thing is I am linked to a database and I need to automate it so I can't really manually add zero's into the data itself.. Can you explain that strategy using TODAY() in tableau itself a little further?

Comment: Maybe have a look at #2 here https://community.tableau.com/thread/152296